# Linking Controller behaviour in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible from a Controller to show a view, and then dependant on what that user selects in dropDownList - render another different view back in the original calling controller?  Kind of a "daisy-chaining" effect.

The thinking behind this - is a user selecting a vehicle type - (associated with an ID number) in a view, back in the Controller dependant on what was chosen will render another view immediately displaying HTML according to the vehicle type they chose e.g. an HTML page for car or a boat or aeroplane etc...

If this is possbile can someone point me to a code examaple?

Actual Database Model below - but it is for documents, not vehicles!

[image]

Comment: do you want to show the new view in the entire page? or a part of a page ? or a model dialog ?

Comment: I think it would be nice to not show a page refresh - but maybe a new page makes sense, not sure???, definitley not a dialog.  But I need to carry forward the id created from the Vehicle page, as this is used as a foriegn key in the next page.

Comment: i added an asnwer. can you show us your model

Comment: I think you should keep that in 2 separate action methods. That makes your code clean and better readable.

Answer (score 2):

check the method paremetares of your action method and return different views baed on that . Something like this.

```
public ActionResult GetInfo(string id,string vehicleTypId)
{
  if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(vehicleTypeId))
  {
    var vehicle=GetVehicleType(vehicleTypId);
    return View("ShowSpecificVehicle",vehicle)    ;
  }

  var genericVehicle=GetVehicle(id);
  return View(genericVehicle);

}
```

**EDIT :** Saying so,  I seriously think you should keep those in 2 seperate Action methods. That makes your code clean and better readable. You may move the common functionality to a function and call if from bothe the action methods id needed. So i would do it in this way

Assuming you have a ViewModel for the first page( displays all vehicletypes)

```
public class VehicleTypesViewModel
{
  //other relevant properties
  public IEnumerable Types { set;get;}
  public int SelectedTypeId { set;get;}
}
```

Your GET request for the initial view will be handled by this action result.It gets all the Vehicle types and return that to your view in the ViewModels Types property.

```
public ActionResult VehicleTypes()
{
  VehicleTypesViewModel objVM=new VehicleTypesViewModel();
  objVM.Types=dbContext.VehicleTypes.ToList();      
  return View(objVM);
}
```

and in your View called VehicleTypes.cshtml,

```
@model VehicleTypesViewModel     
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(Model.SelectedTypeId,new SelectList(Model.Types,"Text",Value"),"Select")
<input type="submit" value="Go" />

}
```

Another Action method to handle the form post. You have the selected type id here and you can get the specific details here and return a different view

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VehicleTypes(VehicleTypesViewModel model)
{
  // you have the selected Id in model.SelectedTypeId property
  var specificVehicle=dbContext.Vehicles.Where(x=>x.TypeId=model.SelectedTypeId);
  return View("SpecificDetails",specificVehicle);

}
```

Alternatively you can do a Get request for the specific vehicle using RedirecToAction method. I would prefer this approach as it sticks with the PRG pattern.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VehicleTypes(VehicleTypesViewModel model)
{
  int typeId=model.SelectedTypeId;
  return RedirectToAction("GetVehicle",new {@id=typeId});
}
public ActionResult GetVehicle(int id)
{
  var specificVehicle=dbContext.Vehicles.Where(x=>x.TypeIdid);
  return View(specificVehicle);

}
```

**With Javascript :** You can do a get call to the new view from your javascript also. without the HTTPpost to controller. You should add some javascript in your initial view for that

```
    @model VehicleTypesViewModel 
    //Include jQuery library reference here    
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model.SelectedTypeId,new SelectList(Model.Types,"Text",Value"),"Select")
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $("#SelectedTypeId").change(){
          window.location.href="@Url.Action("GetVehicle","Yourcontroller")"+"/"+$(this).attr("id");
        });
      });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to get a better user experience create a `partial view`, and load that partial view in a `div` in the same page via an ajax call.

```
public ActionResult GetVehicalInfo(string id, string vehicleType)
{
    var vehicle = GetVehicleType(id, vehicleTypId);
    return PartialView("vehicle);      
}
```